# When canceling an async operation. Throw an TaskCanceledException or just return?

Tags: c#, windows, async-await

When canceling an async operation when should I use this (just return):

```
if( ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;
```

, instead of this (throw an exception):

```
if( ct.IsCancellationRequested) throw new TaskCanceledException(task);
```

Comment: Why not call `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`?

Comment: Yes that one also. But why would I need to throw an exception at all?

Comment: That's up to you. What *do* you want to do? Does the caller of your async method care whether it was cancelled or not?

Comment: If you return then your task will have `RanToCompletion` state. If it is cancelled then it will be `Canceled`. These states can be handled in different ways in a calling method or in continuation. To the best of my knowledge, it is the only significant difference.

Comment: If I'm using a CancellationToken, I expect an `OperationCanceledException` if the token cancels (unless we're past the point of no-return, in which case cancellation becomes a noop). To me, this is the idiomatic way that this is communicated back up the call-stack. Right or wrong, it seems pretty baked in now.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing the exception stops all execution on that code path until an appropriate catch handles the exception. It guarantees the code to stop. Its stop's you having to return multiple times from various methods, potentially checking boolean return values and creating branching logic. The exception just halts everything.

The choice is still up to you, and really depends on the scenario.

Here is some Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-cancellation

One thing thing of note they mentiond is this

> By throwing a OperationCanceledException and passing it the token on which cancellation was requested. The preferred way to do this is to use the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method. A task that is canceled in this way transitions to the Canceled state, which the calling code can use to verify that the task responded to its cancellation request.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you need throw `TaskCanceledException`. `TaskCanceledException` is the result of a cancelled task which holds the `CancellationToken` that matches the token in the `OperationCanceledException` thrown in your task's asynchronous operation.

From your code snippet, it seems you can use:

`ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`

as opposed to the more verbose:

```
if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    throw new OperationCancelledException(ct);
```

But it's unclear which direction to advise ultimately without more context. Use-cases exist for asynchronous operations to cancel/end quietly or via `OperationCancelledException` cancellation.